# C# App database - small, miltiple-form application - forms need to exchange data via database

Tags: c#, database-design, data-structures, database-connection, multiple-forms

To give you some background, the project I am working on is a poker tournament manager. It uses two forms - the main form will display information throughout the tournament, such as players remaining, player names, stakes, payout structure, time left etc; and the other form will be used as a 'setup' form. Both of these forms are built and working, but I am struggling to get them to share data with each other.

What I want to do is load the setup form, select my options for configuring the tournament, and then clicking 'save' will assign all of my options to variables and then write these variables to a database of some kind (I'm new to DB design and I haven't used any DB objects in Visual Studio *yet*). The main form can then read the DB and display the relevant data. The benefits I can see of this is that the tournament setup can be saved for future use, and player stats can be accumulated over time.

What sort of database object do I need to create to store this data, and how do I open connections etc and write data to the DB?

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably suggest that you use LINQ to SQL. ScottGu did an excellent series on blog posts on how to build a model with this. You only really need to read the first few for a simple CRUD application.

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx